# Select2 problem with displaying the retrived data

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

i have a select2 multiple and i am trying to set the selected value to it using jquery
here's my code

```
var zz='1,2';
```

I tried the following two ways, an i have problems with both

```
$('.dataCreate #'+a).select2("val", zz.split(',')).trigger("change");
```

this one display only the tage of the first item in array not all the data

```
$('.dataCreate #'+a).select2().val([zz.split(',')]).trigger("change");
```

this didn't display any tags

Comment: Remove the `.select2()` call and the `[]` around `split()` in your second example and it will work. See the docs: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#selecting-options

Comment: i try it but it didn't display anything `$('.dataCreate  #'+a).val(zz.split(',')).trigger("change");`

Comment: i changed it but it didn't display anything $('.dataCreate  #'+a).val(zz.split(',')).trigger("change");